# Generate sequence of minutes in redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How can I generate a sequence of minutes in redshift?

In postgres this will generate a sequence of minutes over the past day:

```
  SELECT date_trunc('minute', generate_series) as minute
  FROM generate_series(NOW() - '1 day'::interval, NOW(), '1 minute')
```

I'm not sure how to get it to work in redshift though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generate_series()` works in Amazon Redshift, as long as you don't try to join it to data in tables. This is because it runs on the Leader Node, but not on Compute Nodes.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - generate_series(1, 60) * interval '1 minute'
```

Returns:

```
2018-07-09 23:59:00
2018-07-09 23:58:00
2018-07-09 23:57:00
...
```

Comment: ah!  of course!  thanks!   and kind of a pain that it doesn't work on the compute nodes but I'll just create a helper table